# Java OpenSMPP - TCP ZeroWindow

Tags: java, ibm-integration-bus, opensmpp

We are sending high throughput SUBMIT_SM using OpenSMPP. But TCP ZeroWindow is received most of the times. Deliver_SM and SUBMIT_SM_RESP is getting missed. Please suggest how to resolve this.

Kindly add your suggestions specific to Java OpenSMPP API.

Comment: What does this have to do with the [ibm] or [ibm-integration-bus] tags?

Comment: OpenSMPP java API is consumed within a JavaCompute, we have an in-house IIB Application asset available for SMS Sending.

Comment: Your question does not mention IIB or JavaCompute, do these pertain to your actual question?  If not I would suggest you remove the [ibm-itegration-bus] tag.  I am removing [ibm] since it is for questions about the company not about specific products from the company.